# Using conditional statement for label placement of line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, intersection, expression

I have a 'top layer' and a 'bottom layer' and both are line features.

I want the labels of 'bottom layer' to not block 'top layer'. Basically, if 'top layer' intersects/overlap with 'bottom layer', its label would be `BL=Below line`. If not, then `OL=On line`.

[image]

I've tried `if(intersects('top layer', 'bottom layer'), BL,  OL)` and it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need geometries for your input of [`intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#intersects), not layers. Get the current features geometry by using [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#geometry) and the collected MultiLineString-Geometry of the top-layer by using [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate) function. Like:

```
if(intersects($geometry, aggregate('top layer', 'collect', $geometry)), 'BL', 'OL')
```

or [since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) using the [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function also:

```
if(array_length(overlay_intersects('top layer', $geometry)) > 0, 'BL', 'OL')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'm experimenting with other spatial relationsjips and it seems `overlaps()` works better.